# If I am licensing a website to a client, what should the copyright on the site say?

Tags: legal, copyright

I am currently negotiating a license agreement with a former client that I have stopped developing for. Up till now, it was just work based on a verbal agreement. Now as we are going separate ways, we are making sure we are both protected.

As it stands, I own the IP, and the copyright on the site has my name on it. I will be licensing to them to use and to modify themselves as they need. Once the license is set up, what should that copyright on the site say, and how will it change as they develop the site further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copyrights indicate the owner of the IP.

You could do

> © 2018 [Your Company]. Used with permission.

Or

> © 2018 [Your Company]. Licensed to [Client Company].

Or

> Site Contents © [Client Company]
>   Website Design © 2018 [Your Company]